# Data Retreival from Cassandra using spark-cassandra-connector 1.5 for spark version 1.5.2

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

Please let me know how to retrieve data from Cassandra using spark-cassandra-connector 1.5 . My spark version is 1.5.2 . Previously we are using spark 1.4.0 and that was working fine with the given below code.

```
val cassandraContext = new CassandraSQLContext(sc)
 val sqlRDD = cassandraContext.sql(sqlQuery)
```

Now the spark version has changed.In this version, there is a problem in DataStax Spark Connector for Apache Cassandra 1.5 as the link given below

https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-320

So please let me know how to work in this environment.If possible please provide me some sample examples.I am using spark 1.5.2 version. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the comments from the bug

Comment: Now we can't change the spark version as it is dependent on other things. So please let me know is there any other API/methods can we use instead of the previous one. Any possible way please let me know.Thanks.

Comment: You can use the hive context as a workaround

Comment: Thank you RussS for your feedback. Can you please provide me some sample code which I can use as reference.